# Iconos de Formato Condicional de Excel, sin Formato Condicional

Tags: excel, vba, formato-condicional

Quiero ocupar los íconos del formato condicional, como la bandera verde y roja; pero sin ocupar el formato condicional. La idea es:

```
If numero <= 0 Then
    'rt.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    'Aquí va una Bandera Verde
Else
    'rt.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    'Aquí va una Bandera Roja
End If
```

No puedo ocupar el formato condicional ya que el valor de la celda es algo como "Banco1 = 123456", además el 123456 es el resultado de una formula bastante compleja.

En resumen, ¿Cómo ocupo, llamo o referencio esos íconos del Formato Condicional?

Comment: ¿Y eso cómo sería?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los iconos de formato condicional, sólo aplican a **celdas con valores numéricos**, y no existe una forma de insertar esos iconos desde código.

Una alternativa sencilla es crear una nueva columna al lado, que extraiga sólo el número de tus valores. Por ejemplo, asumiendo que todos tus valore siguen el formato `nombre = valor`, podemos:

1. Buscar la posición en la que se encuentra el `" = "`.

   ```
   ENCONTRAR(" = ";A1)
   ```

   <sup><sup>* Se asume que la celda con el valor está en A1</sup></sup>
2. Obtener el texto luego de esa posición, hasta el final

   ```
   EXTRAE(A1; ENCONTRAR(" = ";A1) + 3; 9999)
   ```
3. Convertir todo a número

   ```
   =VALOR(EXTRAE(A1;ENCONTRAR(" = ";A1) + 3;9999))
   ```

Sobre esta nueva columna, es sencillo establecer un formato condicional con iconos, seleccionando sólo los valores entre los cuales aplican:

[image: Limites con -9999999 y 0]

---

Si aún te interesa realizarlo desde código:

```vb
Sub FormatoConBanderas()
    'Rangos a aplicar
    Dim celdaInicial As Range
    Dim columnaIconos As Range
    Set celdaInicial = Range("A1")
    Set columnaIconos = Range("B1:B6")

    'Formato
    celdaInicial.Select
    With columnaIconos
        .FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            .ShowIconOnly = True
            .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3TrafficLights1)
            'Rojo negativos
            .IconCriteria(1).Icon = xlIconRedFlag
            'Rojo para el cero
            With .IconCriteria(2)
                .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
                .Value = 0
                .Operator = 7
                .Icon = xlIconRedFlag
            End With
            'Verde positivos
            With .IconCriteria(3)
                .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
                .Value = 0
                .Operator = 5
                .Icon = xlIconGreenFlag
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Vale. Aunque lo que quería, era hacerlo en la misma celda, me faltó explicar eso. Quería que quedara como "Banco1 = 1234 [Bandera verde]"; ya que no tengo espacio. Hasta ahora le cambio el color a la celda, pero las banderitas se hubiesen visto mas bonitas.
De todas maneras, tu respuesta sería lo mas simple y el saber que no se puede, tal como quiero, me deja mas tranquilo.
Muchas gracias.